# How can I expand an email thread Gmail on Android?

Tags: gmail

How can I expand an email thread Gmail on Android?

When looking at Gmail in a web browser I can do:

[image]

I'm looking for the same option for Android.

Comment: In Gmail settings > youraccount@gmail.com > untick "Conversation view". Emails should then be expanded by default.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio thanks, unfortunately that would display emails from the same conversation as independent emails, which I don't want. Sorry I've just realised that the red arrow in the first screenshot doesn't point to the right option: it should point to conversion view on.

Comment: I would recommend you to try out [FairEmail](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/source-email-t3824168/page1138) an open source, privacy oriented email client, which can provide far greater customization than Gmail app